# Getting IndexOutOfRangeException without going out of the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, encryption, indexoutofboundsexception

So I have the code bellow to create an encrypted string using `orgTxt` and `rndTxt`, when I debug the code in Visual Studio I get an error of IndexOutOfRangeException in the second `for` loop.

I check the value of the index with breakpoints and it seems perfectly in range, anyone has an idea what the problem is?
If more information needed to help solve this error just leave me comment please.

```
//variables
    string scrtTxt = null;
    string rndTxt = null;
    string orgTxt = reader.ReadToEnd();

//assigning random a string from key (set of all capital letters) to rndTxt
for (int i = 0; i < fileInfo.Length; i++) 
        {
             rndTxt += key[random.Next(0, key.Length)]; 
        }

//generating the encrypted message scrtTxt
 int j = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < fileInfo.Length; i++)
       {
            if ((orgTxt[i] + rndTxt[j] - 'A') <= 'Z' && (orgTxt[i] + rndTxt[j] - 'A') >= 'A')
                    scrtTxt += Convert.ToChar((orgTxt[i] + rndTxt[j] - 'A'));

            if ((orgTxt[i] + rndTxt[j] - 'A') > 'Z')
                    scrtTxt += (char)(scrtTxt[i] - 'Z' + 'A' - 1);//IndexOutOfRangeException error here

            j = j + 1 == rndTxt.Length ? 0 : j + 1;
       }
```

Comment: `scrtTxt` must be less than `i+1` characters long at that point. Double-check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading from `scrtTxt` array in this line of code.

```
scrtTxt += (char)(scrtTxt[i] - 'Z' + 'A' - 1);
```

Is that what you wanted to do or it should be orgTxt or rndTxt?

Comment: oops my mistake, yes that's the problem, I have to read from orgTxt. Thanks nick-s